# First order higher degree ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Considering the ODE
$$\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^n+C_1y=C_2$$
where, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants.

Is there a way to find an analytical or approximate analytical solution to this ODE in terms of $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a analytical solution to this ODE:
\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^{n}+C_{1}y & =C_{2}
\end{align*}
If we solve for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$:
\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^{n} & =C_{2}-C_{1}y\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} & =\left(C_{2}-C_{1}y\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
\end{align*}
Integrating:
\begin{align*}
\int\left(C_{2}-C_{1}y\right)^{-\frac{1}{n}}dy & =\int dx\\
-\frac{1}{C_{1}}\int-C_{1}\left(C_{2}-C_{1}y\right)^{-\frac{1}{n}}dy & =\int dx\\
\begin{cases}
\frac{n}{n-1}\left(C_{2}-C_{1}y\right)^{\frac{n}{n-1}} & n>1\\
\log\left(C_{2}-C_{1}y\right) & n=1
\end{cases} & =x+k
\end{align*}
You can finally solve for $y(x)$:
\begin{align*}
y\left(x\right) & =\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{C_{1}}\left(C_{2}-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\left(x+k\right)\right)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\right) & n>1\\
\frac{1}{C_{1}}\left(C_{2}-e^{x+k}\right) & n=1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}